# Python program for STV voting system, add all the first preference votes for each candidate

Tags: python, arrays

Firstly, I have a text file which shows the voting scores of 5 candidates in 4 ballots below:

1, 2, 3, 0, 0

2, 3, 1, 0, 0

3, 1, 0, 0, 2

0, 2, 0, 3, 1

Voters put their first three preferences and the two remaining candidates get zeros.

Using the program below, each scores for each candidate gets put in a 2dimensional array and the quota is calculated.

```
with open("textdata.txt","r") as f:
    ReadTextFile = f.read()

RawVotesArray = ReadTextFile.split("\n")
TwoDArrayRows = [item for item in RawVotesArray if item != ""]
TwoDArrayRows = [item.split(",") for item in TwoDArrayRows]
print(TwoDArrayRows)

CandidateA = [row[0] for row in TwoDArrayRows]
Preference1CA = CandidateA.count("1")

CandidateB = [row[1] for row in TwoDArrayRows]
Preference1CB = CandidateB.count("1")

CandidateC = [row[2] for row in TwoDArrayRows]
Preference1CC = CandidateC.count("1")

CandidateD = [row[3] for row in TwoDArrayRows]
Preference1CD = CandidateD.count("1")

CandidateE = [row[4] for row in TwoDArrayRows]
Preference1CE = CandidateE.count("1")

ValidVotes = 4
NumberOfSeats = 2
quota = int((ValidVotes/(NumberOfSeats + 1))+1)
print(quota)
```

The output to this is:

[['1', ' 2', ' 3', ' 0', ' 0'], ['2', ' 3', ' 1', ' 0', ' 0'], ['3', ' 1', ' 0', ' 0', ' 2'], ['0', ' 2', ' 0', ' 3', ' 1']]
2

The 2 at the end is the quota. For a candidate to win, the total of their first preference votes (the 1s) have to reach or exceed the quota of 2. I do not know how to code a function so that the first preference votes of each candidate are added up together.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful what you are counting. If you look closely, you are counting `"1"`, but because of the way you read your votes in, you could have `"1"` or `" 1"`. To get around this, read your file in line by line and remove any leading/trailing spaces by using `.strip()`:

```
votes = []

with open("textdata.txt","r") as f_input:
    for line in f_input:
        if len(line.strip()):
            votes.append([value.strip() for value in line.split(',')])
```

This will also strip the trailing newline of the last value in each line. `votes` would then contain:

```
[['1', '2', '3', '0', '0'], ['2', '3', '1', '0', '0'], ['3', '1', '0', '0', '2'], ['0', '2', '0', '3', '1']]
```

To total up all the first preference votes you could use [`index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) to tell you where the `1` is in the list (`0` being the first location). With this you could keep a total for each using a list of counters:

```
candidate_first_pref = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

for vote in votes:
    candidate_first_pref[vote.index('1')] += 1

print(candidate_first_pref)
```

So at the end your `candidate_first_pref` would have:

```
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```